# Problems with Java in OSX Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, netbeans-8

I'm trying to install Netbeans 8 but the installer is not finding JDK.

But, I can't update my Java, I installed the update 51 of java 7 but when I go in terminal I get it:

```
Alessandros-MacBook:~ alessandrogarcez$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

In "System preferences", I have version 7 installed.

[image]

It seems to have both version of java installed in my mac.

Someone can help me to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: This could be a `$PATH` issue. Could you add the output from running `echo $PATH` in your shell of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to install jre-7u45-macosx-x64.dmg and I don't know why it doesn't overwrite java 6.

I've read a lot of topics, tried all of them.
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US
http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~simpkins/teaching/gatech/cs2340/guides/java7-macosx.html

After all of it, I just downloaded jdk-7u51-macosx-x64.dmg and it worked. The version 7 overwrited the 6.

```
Alessandros-MacBook:~ alessandrogarcez$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The JDK and the JRE are not the same thing.  On Mac the JRE installs in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`, the JDK (which includes the compiler) installs under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.  And the command line `/usr/bin/java` tool uses JDKs, not JREs.

Comment: Your Java 7 JDK installation didn't "overwrite" Java 6, it installed alongside.  You can switch the `java` command between the two by setting your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable appropriately.  Run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to list all the available JDKs.